# How can a struct member be changed in a loop in C++

Tags: c++

I have a vector of structs and i want to modify members of structs in a for loop. Actual code is much longer so i have a minimalistic case that reproduces my noobish problem:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<Person> People;
    Person Bob;
    Bob.name = "Bob";
    Bob.age = 20;
    People.emplace_back(Bob);
    Person Alice;
    Alice.name = "Alice";
    Alice.age = 19;
    People.emplace_back(Alice);

    for (Person person:People)
    {
        std::cout << person.name << '\t' << person.age << std::endl;
    }

    for (Person person:People)
    {
        person.name = "new name";
        std::cout << person.name << '\t' << person.age << std::endl;
    }
    
    for (Person person:People)
    {
        std::cout << person.name << '\t' << person.age << std::endl;
    }
}
```

When ran, this code will output:

```
Bob 20
Alice   19
new name    20
new name    19
Bob 20
Alice   19
```

but i need it to be:

```
Bob 20
Alice   19
new name    20
new name    19
new name    20
new name    19
```

If this was inside of function I would pass values by reference and it would hopefully change the value. However I don't know why the above code doesn't actually modify values outside the for loops.

Comment: In `(Person person : People)`, you need to define `person` as a reference (essentially `(Person &person : People)`, in order to be able to modify it. The code you have right now passes `person` by *value*, meaning that a temporary copy of each `Person` object is created for each iteration that does not actually affect the value contained within the `vector`.

Comment: yey, that was just as it works for functions, can you please post answer so i can accept it

Comment: yes in a way that would also answer my questio but somehow it didn't come up since i specifically googled structs